# What the name of this coin cell battery and its holder?

Tags: batteries

I searched a lot on the internet for any small holder. The smallest I could find was holder for CR1220.

Does such battery and holder sizes even exist?

[image: Battery Socket]

Comment: I don't think it's a place for a holder. It's for leads connected to the battery. http://www.jameco.com/z/CR1220-WIRE-LEADS-3V-CR1220-Lithium-Coin-Cell-Battery-with-Leads_2210010.html

Comment: That's John the coin battery, who's currently out of the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That footprint is not for a holder.  It looks like it's meant for a coin cell with solderable leads.  From the "RTC" and the watch crystal, it looks like the battery is for keeping a low power clock running when 5 V isn't supplied on the IIC interface.

I'll guess that a 3 V battery would work fine.  Look around on the a distributor site like Mouser for the largest capacity 3 V leaded coin cell you can find that fits mechanically.  You have considerable leeway for the cell diameter, up to just under 10 mm maximum.  8 mm looks like it would be a comfortable fit.

Panasonic is one supplier of such batteries.  They are not hard to find.

Comment: My answer was shorter this time